# How to sync a lot of buckets from shell or python

Tags: amazon-web-services, synchronization

I can use `aws s3 ls` to list buckets like this:

```
$aws s3 ls --endpoint http://XXXXXX
...
2022-08-22 16:47:37 cluster-back
2022-08-23 11:54:46 dog
2022-09-08 10:22:41 kesci-annotations
2022-09-08 10:22:59 kesci-datasets-ng
2022-09-08 10:23:13 kesci-datasets-ng-parsed-meta
2022-09-08 10:25:07 kesci-model-service-input
2022-09-08 10:25:39 kesci-model-service-output
2022-09-08 10:26:09 kesci-workspace-ng
2022-09-08 10:26:39 kesci-workspace-ng-parsed-meta
...
```

How can I use shell or python to sync all of the buckets without having to provide all of the bucket names?

I then want to use this shell or python to kubernetes`s cronjob.

Comment: What is the **source** and **destination** for such a sync? That is, where do you want to copy **from** and where do you want to copy it **to**?

Comment: the source from my minio ,want sync to one of my kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 0):

The `aws s3 sync` command will copy from one source path to one destination path. The source path would include the bucket name. Therefore, you would need to run one `sync` command per bucket.

You could first run a command to retrieve all the bucket names:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[].[Name]' --output text
```

This will output each bucket name on a separate line.

You could then pass these bucket names into `xargs` to generate multiple `aws s3 sync` commands that will copy all the buckets.

Comment: ty, As I thought ，but its not Intelligent

Comment: An alternative would be to write code in Python to perform the operation. However, the AWS CLI `sync` command uses multiple threading and is highly efficient. It would be difficult to code multi-threading yourself for the copy operations.